# Сослагательное наклонение для обозначения нереального действия в будущем

Tags: сослагательное-наклонение

Стараюсь найти примеры, выражающие нереальное действие в будущем. Вот плод моей фантазии:

> Если бы я полетела на Луну, я была бы первым человеком из своей семьи,
>   кто полетел в космос.

И здесь я запуталась: с одной стороны, думаю, что эту ситуацию вполне можно считать гипотетической (под девизом nothing is impossible), может когда-нибудь такой день придет, God knows. Но с другой стороны, зная, что я и моя семья к космонавтике и т. п. не имеем никакого отношения, шансы на то, что это произойдет, равны нулю. Как вы это видите? Если вы можете дать ваши примеры для сравнения, буду рада!

Answer (score 3):

Нереальные действия - это и Ваш пример (маловозможная ситуация для Вашей семьи), и фантастические, например:

Если бы к нам прилетел корабль с инопланетянами, мы бы подружились с пришельцами.

И вполне реальные, но при упущенной возможности:

Если бы я поторопился и  успел на этот поезд, я бы завтра увидел своих друзей. **Будущее действие нереально,** т.к. возможность упущена.

Answer (score 2):

С помощью сослагательного наклонения выражается:

**1)  Предположительное условие (может реализоваться в будущем)**

Это условия, отнесенные к будущему, но их не называют нереальными, это **предположительные** условия, которые еще могут осуществиться (правда, с разной вероятностью, иногда она близка к нулю).

Если бы я полетела на Луну (предположение), я была бы первым человеком из своей семьи, кто полетел в космос.

Если бы иметь экстрасенсорные способности, то можно было бы предвидеть будущее.

Если бы мы нашли карту, то нашли бы и спрятанные сокровища.

Вот если бы ты всегда и везде, всю свою жизнь оставлял для людей только хорошее - цветы, мысли, славные воспоминания о тебе, - легка и приятна была бы твоя жизнь (М. Горький).

**2) Ирреальное (нереальное) условие (относится к прошлому)**

Нереальное условие относится к  **несостоявшемуся (контрфактическому) действию в прошлом (упущенная возможность)**: Если бы не было дождя (а дождь был), мы пошли бы гулять.

Comment: cпасибо за ответ! Вопрос к предложению "Если бы мы нашли карту, то нашли бы и спрятанные сокровища." Я думаю, его можно и как упущенная возможность рассматривать, нет? получается: здесь нужен широкий контекст, чтобы понять как правильно сказанное интерпретировать?

Comment: В принципе Вы правы, здесь возможны две ситуации. Если эти сокровища уже кто-то нашел, то это упущенная возможность, нам они уже не достанутся. Но если они еще не найдены, то у нас  еще сохраняется возможность найти карту, а по ней найти сокровища.

Answer (score 1):

Если б я был султан,

Я б имел трёх жён

И тройной красотой

Был бы окружён.

(Популярная песенка)

Answer (score 1):

Самые известные предложения (думаю, и Вам тоже):

*"Кабы я была царица, —

Говорит одна девица, —

То на весь крещеный мир

Приготовила б я пир".

"Кабы я была царица, —

Говорит ее сестрица, —

То на весь бы мир одна

Наткала я полотна".*
(Александр Сергеевич Пушкин. Сказка о царе Салтане)

*Если бы, да кабы, да во рту росли грибы, тогда бы был не рот, а целый огород.*
(русская пословица)

"Сослагательное — для обозначения нереального в будущем":

Будь [если бы было] у меня четыре ноги — я бы бегала быстрее гепарда.
Если бы я была волшебницей, то сделала бы всех людей счастливыми.
Если бы было возможно отмотать двадцать лет назад, я бы исправила все свои ошибки.

Comment: А девица-то стала царицей! Что ж тут нереального?

Comment: Третья — да! — но я ведь про нее ничего и не писала... И богатыря родила...

Comment: У Вас здесь нет грамматического будущего. Аскер категорически настроен на нахождения примеров, строго соответствующих аналогам в её родном языке. Единственный сносный пример - у Людмилы. В русском просто нет формальных показателей для разделения сослагательного реального и нереального будущего.

Comment: Нашла эту сказку. Получается, первые две сестры представляли действие (замужество на царе) как ирреальное и только зная широкий контекст читатель может оценить слова третьей сестры как гипотетичекие, так?

Comment: Здесь условия  во всех трех случаях предположительные (гипотетические), ирреальных нет.  (Последующий контекст на грамматику не влияет). Ирреальное условие: Вот если бы ты тогда сказала что-нибудь поумнее, то вышла бы замуж за царя (а теперь царицей стала третья сестра, возможность упущена).

Comment: @Anonym Вы спрашивали о нереальном БУДУЩЕМ. Даже если две из сестер станут царицами, ни одна из них НЕ СМОЖЕТ ни наткать полотна, ни приготовить пир на весь мир. Их обещание - ирреально.

Comment: @Римма Михайлова Важно различать ирреальность в грамматике и семантике. Нереальные обещания сестер - это всего лишь художественный прием, гипербола.